# Firebase auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have been following a course on Firebase, but quickly discovered a lot of things have changed. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-createusercredentials
these docs are completely outdated.

Here I declare my firebase variables

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
var firebasedata = $firebaseObject(ref);
var auth = $firebaseAuth();
```

Then I try to call this function

```
this.register = function() {
  auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword({
    email: this.user.email, 
    password: this.user.password
  }).then(function(regUser) {
    $log.log(regUser);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    $log.log(error);
  });
};
```

But it throws this error:

> code
>   :
>   "auth/argument-error"
>   message
>   :
>   "createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string."

I have searched for answers to this problem but all I can find is updating my angularfire or firebase (which are both the latest version) or that this.user.email is not a string. When I do a

```
 console.log(this.user.email);
```

I can see it is a string containing a valid e-mail.

Any help into the right direction would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone experiencing this issue:

the old

> `auth.$createUser()`

function took an user-object as parameter.

While:

> `auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`

takes 2 strings as parameters, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from

```
auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword({
    email: this.user.email, 
    password: this.user.password
})
```

to

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function parameters as follows:

```
this.register = function() {
  auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email,this.user.password).then(function(regUser) {
    $log.log(regUser);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    $log.log(error);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.register = function() {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password)
        .then(function(user) {
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    //}
}
```

here, you can use it this way.